# Scalatra test failing using ScalatraSuite (FunSuiteLike) for standlone sbt project

Tags: scala, jetty, scalatest, scalatra

I am attempting to run a test for a Scalatra route using `ScalatraSuite` (`FunSuiteLike`). I receive an `IllegalArgumentException` with the following error when running the test:

> **The detected local port is < 1, that's not allowed**

I also tried running Jetty separately and then running "sbt test", but the same error comes up. Can anyone please help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

I had this same error and was able to figure out what the cause was.

In my case, I had mixed in a trait that had overridden the `beforeAll` and `afterAll` methods. This meant that the `beforeAll` and `afterAll` defined in ScalatraSuite were not being run. Here's the quote from [Scalatra's documentation for ScalatraSuite](https://scalatra.org/guides/2.3/testing/scalatest.html) that helped me to figure out what the problem was:

> Notice that all the above traits are based on `ScalatraSuite` which
>   mixes in `BeforeAndAfterAll`. It overrides both `beforeAll()` and
>   `afterAll()` so it can start/stop the embedded HTTP server. Because of
>   that, if your test classes also need to override `beforeAll` and/or
>   `afterAll` just remember to call `super.beforeAll()` and/or
>   `super.afterAll()`.

Since my custom `beforeAll` hook was not invoking `super.beforeAll()`, Scalatra's mechanism to launch the HTTP server was not invoked, and thus no test-server was running. Adding the `super.beforeAll()` to my custom `beforeAll` method fixed the problem.

In my case, I had to redesign the `beforeAll` steps in my project, so that a number of different dependencies could be set up... but I was able to ensure that `beforeAll()` in `ScalatraSuite` was called.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but I ran into this same error and found that it was specific tests that would throw this error, not all.  My issue ended up being a code formatting problem where a misplaced `{` made a single test encompass other tests.

So ultimately, if tests have been running and then stop with this error, its very likely a code related issue.  I found this in scalatra.specs2, but the same could happen in ScalatraSuite.

Hope you worked out your issue.